# My available updates has errors

Tags: updating

I'm getting these errors on my available updates page:

> Notice: Undefined index: reason in theme_update_report() (line 86 of
>   D:\Sites\technology2\modules\update\update.report.inc). Notice:
>   Undefined index: in theme_update_report() (line 137 of
>   D:\Sites\technology2\modules\update\update.report.inc). Warning:
>   date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given
>   in format_date() (line 2040 of
>   D:\Sites\technology2\includes\common.inc). Warning: date_format()
>   expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date()
>   (line 2050 of D:\Sites\technology2\includes\common.inc).

I'm not sure where to look for an answer to these errors. I've tried setting my time zone, but that didn't change anything. Thanks in advance!